# OpenSSL: bad magic number

Tags: openssl

I want to decrypt a file, I run:

```
openssl enc -d -aes128 -in encrypted.txt -out decrypted.txt
```

It asked me this:

```
enter aes-128-cbc decryption password:
```

Whatever I type, I get this: `bad magic number`
I did not find an answer on this forum when I checked similar question. Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161716/bad-magic-number-error-when-trying-to-decrypt-file-in-openssl